# Database design for dynamic form

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to create a partially dynamic form. Several fields will be saved into the `training_session` table, Tags are being saved into the `tags` table and connected to the training session via `training_tags`. However, besides these fields that have to be dynamic. If you look at this picture, you will get the idea:

[image]

I'm struggling to design the database for these dynamic fields, though. I came up with something like this:

**field_types**

```
 id - self explanatory
 type - holds the value int or string
```

**fields**

```
id - same
id_field_type - which type of value does the field hold?
label - could also be "name", I guess. Just to know, which field it actually is
value - the actual value of the field
```

What are the best practices and solutions for problems like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged MySQL, it appears you're looking for a relational database design.  A relational database is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to eliminate data duplication.

Looking at your form, we can create 7 database tables; Training Session, Tag, Training Session Tag, Dive, Training Session Dive, Equipment, and Training Session Equipment.  You already came up with 2 of the tables.  Generally, table names are singular.

So, let's look at how you define a Training Session table.

```
Training Session
----------------
Training Session ID
Training Session Title
Training Session Description
Training Session Time Stamp
Training Session Duration
```

The Training Session ID is an auto-incrementing integer or long, and is also the primary or clustering key of the table.  The rest of the attributes should be self-explanatory.

The next table we'll look at is Tag.

```
Tag
---
Tag ID
Tag Name
Tag Description
...
```

Like the Training Session table, the Tag ID is the primary key for this table.  The Tag table holds one row for each of the **possible** tags that can be applied to a training session.

Now, we have training sessions and we have tags.  The next step is to associate the training sessions with the appropriate tags.  For this, we'll create a junction table, Training Session Tag.

```
Training Session Tag
--------------------
Training Session ID
Tag ID
...
```

The primary key for this table is the combination of Training Session ID and Tag ID.  This gives you the tags for a particular training session.  If you want the training sessions for a particular tag, you'll need an additional unique index on (Tag ID, Training Session ID).

I think you can figure out the Dive and Equipment tables, and the Training Session Dive and Training Session Equipment junction tables from here.

Comment: Well, actually pretty simple. I think my initial idea of this form was a bit more complicated, but looking at it now, your suggestion makes perfect sense. I guess, I was starting to miss the forest for the trees, which is why I came up with this field_type and field stuff. Thanks, I'm gonna go with this suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can have both sql and nosql set up for this application. Main structure use SQL relational database, nosql for variable and dynamic data